# Reductions but no algorithms

Tags: turing-machines, reductions, rice-theorem

in "Introduction to Automata Theory, Languages and Computations" by Motwani, Ullman and Hopcroft, when they need to prove, for instance, Rice's theorem, they reduce the universal language, $L_u$, to the language $L_p$, where the latter is defined as the language containing the codes (binary) of all the TM $M$ such that $L(M) \in P$, where $P$ is a non-trivial property of $RE$ languages.

In the proof, they don't give the algorithm that converts an instance of $L_u$, $(M,w)$, to an instance of $L_p$, $<M'>$, but they give a description of $M'$, saying that this should be sufficient to convince the reader that a TM able to perform a conversion from $(M,w)$ to $<M'>$ exists.

I don't understand how this should be sufficient to convice myself that an instance-conversion algorithm exists. I mean: we are only describing $M'$, how can we be sure a TM is able to take $(M,w)$ as input and give us the binary code of $M'$?

Answer (score 1):

This is very common.  Specifying a Turing machine formally is super tedious and often not very insightful.  It amounts to implementing a program, in a horribly inconvenient programming language.  Writers typically assume that you already know how to write programs and that you can figure out how to implement something as a Turing machine, and leave it up to you to fill in those tedious details.

For instance, if I give you pseudocode of an algorithm, I am presuming that you will know how to turn that into an implementation.  Same deal in these theorems: the author is trusting that you will know how to turn that description into an algorithm and then into code.